# Set the title for a node view panel

Tags: 8, panels

I am trying to use panel in Drupal 8 node view template. I have enable Node view panel and added a new variant for Basic page view. But I couldn't mention in panel page to take the title as current node title. Where I can mention it in panel configuration?

**Drupal 8**
[image]

Even I have created the panel variant in Drupal 7. Here title is taking by default node title.

**Drupal 7**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

FYI: Page Manager is in beta, but that doesn't affect the solution; see below.

You should first check if the `node` context is available in your Variant. Here is an example screenshot for that:

[image]

If that is the case, then you can simply use the following token in the page title field:

> [node:title]

should look like this:

[image]

Good luck!